# having two dataframes, how to create a third one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe df1

```
    col1    val1
1   a       2
2   b       3
```

and df2 (different length)

```
    col2    val2
1   A       2
2   B       3
3   C       1
```

i need a third df that would look like this

```
    colx    coly    sum
1   a       A       4
2   a       B       5
3   a       C       3
4   b       A       5
5   b       B       3
6   b       C       4
```

so the number of rows in df3 is `df1.shape[0] * df2.shape[0]`, and a third column is added where i do calculations on the values (in this case for the sake of simplicity it's just sum). The third df has rows that represent the relations between a value from `df1` and all the values from `df2` one by one.

here's what i've tried, but i don't think this is a good way to do this

```
cols = [colx, coly, sum]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        df3.append({'colx': row['col1'], 'coly': row2['col2'], 'sum': row['val1']+row2['val2']}, ignore_index=True)
```

i don't really know how to describe this in the title, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cross` merge with `sum`, [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is for removed columns after sum:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
df['sum'] = df.pop('val1') + df.pop('val2')
print (df)
  col1 col2  sum
0    a    A    4
1    a    B    5
2    a    C    3
3    b    A    5
4    b    B    6
5    b    C    4
```

Or is possible create `Series`, then [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
s1 = df1.set_index('col1')['val1']
s2 = df2.set_index('col2')['val2']

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s1.index, s2.index])

df = (s1.reindex(mux, level=0) + s2.reindex(mux, level=1)).reset_index(name='sum')
print (df)
  col1 col2  sum
0    a    A    4
1    a    B    5
2    a    C    3
3    b    A    5
4    b    B    6
5    b    C    4
```